# Batch Script: How can I create a blacklist?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a blacklist of elements which should be skipped at the run time. I have some batch files which must be executed, but some of them are not working properly so until they are fixed i want to skip them for now.

This is what I am trying to do right now:

```
@set BLACKLIST=(element1, element2, element3)

REM Call the ut.bat files only if they are outside the blacklist,
REM otherwise skip them.

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b ut.bat') do (
    for %%j in %BLACKLIST% do (
        if /I not "%%~dpi" == "%~dp0%%j\" (
            CALL %%i
        )
))
```

Comment: Why was this originally tagged "bash"?

Comment: "some of them" - those which have a space in the name? `call "%%i"` will cure that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@set BLACKLIST=(element1, element2, element3)

REM Call the ut.bat files only if they are outside the blacklist,
REM otherwise skip them.

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b ut.bat') do (
    if "!BLACKLIST:%%~dpi=!" equ "%BLACKLIST%" (
        CALL %%i
    )
)
```

The `"!BLACKLIST:%%~dpi=!"` part tries to *delete* the name of the current Batch file from the blacklist. If such a file is *not* in the list the list remain the same, so in this case call the Batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that for any directory found, your code will run if that code does not match element1, and again if it does not match element2 and so on. Since it cannot match **both** element1 and element2, then it will run at least once.

```
@set "BLACKLIST=element1, element2, element3"

REM Call the ut.bat files only if they are outside the blacklist,
REM otherwise skip them.

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b ut.bat') do (
    SET "RUNME=Y"
    for %%j in (%BLACKLIST%) do (
            if /I "%%~dpi" == "%~dp0%%j\" SET "RUNME="
    )
    IF DEFINED RUNME CALL %%i
)
```

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

First. for every directory encountered, set `runme` to a value.

If the directory is on the blacklist, set `runme` to *nothing*, which un-defines it.

Only if the directory is not on the blacklist will every `if` fail and `runme` survive, set to *something*